# perl Net::FTP ls no matches

Tags: perl

```
my $u = URI->new('ftp://myuri');
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($u->host(), Debug => 1) or die "Connection failed!";

$ftp->login($u->user(), $u->password()) or die "Login failed!";
$ftp->cwd($u->path()) or die "CWD failed!";
$ftp->binary();

my @ls = $ftp->ls('S*.txt') or die "LIST failed!" . $ftp->code();

foreach $line (@ls) {
    print "### $line\n";
}
```

This code will die bacause ls has not any matches, it is possile to determine if ls() was successful but with no matches or there was other error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Net::FTP is derived from Net::Cmd, so you should look into the documentation of Net::Cmd too. There you can see, that `$ftp->ok` can be used to check if the last command was ok even if it returned no data.